# is there a writing program(MS word, Libre office...) that can type long vowels in Latin?

Tags: discussion

I have been wishing to write out long vowels of Latin in typing, so I am looking for a way to do that in Libre office. But I don't think there is any way in Libre office other than inserting "symbols".

Is there any other writing program that allows long vowels?

Comment: Which platform are you on? And how do you feel about switching your keyboard layout?

Comment: windows. Is there a keyboard layout that types long vowels?

Comment: @Sean Take a look at the question in Joonas's comment. I also use Windows and found that using a Maori keyboard was the perfect solution (in my case, to type transliterated Greek).

Comment: I moved this over from the main page to Meta, and since we already have a thread on this topic, I marked it duplicate. Let us know if you it doesn't answer your question, though.

Comment: I recommend a plug-in program called WinCompose, which allows you type diacritic letters like é, ç, ā, without changing your keyboard scheme.